# How to add specific div to form find

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

Below is the code which is working fine. But it find all inputs from the whole form . How can I include/omit the div inisde the form.

```
var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm")); 

function checkFields(form) {
    var checks_radios = form.find(':checkbox, :radio'); 
    var inputs = form.find(':input').not(checks_radios).not('[type="submit"],[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="hidden"]'); 
    var checked = checks_radios.filter(':checked'); 
    var filled = inputs.filter(function(){
            var newvalue = $(this).val(); 
            var newval = $.trim($(this).val()); 
            return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
        }); 
    if(checked.length + filled.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else{  
        return true;}
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="#" th:object="${person}"  method="post">
   <div id="includethisdiv">
         // Include contents of this div for checking.
   </div>
   <div id="omitthisdiv">
         // Omit this div for checking.
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use second argument which defines parent for jquery selector `inputs = $("input", $("#includethisdiv", "#searchForm"));`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the below line :

```
var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm"));
```

as

```
var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm #includethisdiv"));
```